# Neo4J Desktop Initialization error: Error: end of central directory record signature not found

Tags: neo4j

I got this error when the setup program is "Extracting Java 8". This solution (https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/extracting-java-error-during-neo4j-desktop-install/) doesn't help because %APPDATA%/Neo4j Desktop/Application/distributions/java/ was not created.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the file found under:

C:\Users\[USERNAME]\.Neo4jDesktop\distributions\java

It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem!
In the end found the java directory in the installation directory (I believe it was, I just searched for 'java' from here on). Next I found a file named `zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-win_x64.zip`.

I removed this file, and got a different error message: it could not find the file `zulu8.21.0.1-jdk8.0.131-win_x64.zip.tmp`, so I put back the file I removed, and added `.tmp` to its name, and now it works!